# Excel FIND and REPLACE functions for unique numbering

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below Excel formula to help auto-number rows on a sheet to be unique. I want to FIND the first occurrence of the dash character (-) and add 1 to the number immediately to the right of it.

Here is the formula I am using to do that: It find the number to the right of the first dash (5) and adds 1 to it, resulting in a value of 6.

`=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A11,7),"-",REPLACE(A11,1,FIND("-",A11),"")+1)`

[image]

This works fine if there is only one dash (-) character in the string being searched, however my data will have 3 dashes in it, and when I have a string with multiple dashes in it, then I get a #VALUE error. How can I fix this to find the number to the right of the first dash in the string and add 1 to it in this case?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could use the SUBSTITUTE formula to replace the first instance with another character and then reference that.

Comment: I see the length of your string varies, is this by design or the result of formulas? I'm trying to find the pattern, will it always lead with 8 characters before the numbers you want to do math to? Do the endings vary like we have here?

Comment: Yes it will always lead with 8 characters before the first dash occurs. The values will ultimately look like what you see in cells A8 - A10

Comment: @Nick thanks for the info. I added my formula that seems to do the trick in my testing. The key assumption to this formula is that the length of the string and it's format matches `A8:A10`, like you had mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put these formulas, substituting where I put [cell] with the cells your referencing. It's an ugly formula, I know but it breaks this down a few ways.

First, it takes the leftmost characters prefixing the number to do math to and adds that text to the calculation. The calculation separates all the text before and after that numbers, converts it to value, adds 1, then combines that to the prefix. Lastly, it takes the suffix and adds it to the prefix and mid.

There might be an opportunity to use a `Mid` formula; however, I was unsure how many characters the number could reach so I kept this variable.

`=LEFT([Cell],8) & VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT([Cell],FIND("-",[Cell],9)-1),LEN(LEFT([Cell],FIND("-",[Cell],9)-1))-FIND("-",LEFT([Cell],FIND("-",[Cell],9)-1))))+1 & "-" & RIGHT([Cell],LEN([Cell])-FIND("-",[Cell],9))`

Using your cell references:

`=LEFT(A11,8) & VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A11,FIND("-",A11,9)-1),LEN(LEFT(A11,FIND("-",A11,9)-1))-FIND("-",LEFT(A11,FIND("-",A11,9)-1))))+1 &"-"& RIGHT(A11,LEN(A11)-FIND("-",A11,9))`

Comment: Mark I tried this, replacing [CELL] with the actual cell (A11) and I am getting a formula error.

Comment: @Nick I made a minor adjustment so the result would match the format of the cell in case that was getting in the way. I also wrote the formula to use your reference just in case at some point during the transposition it got changed.

Comment: Great this seems to be working well, even if I have additional digits after the dash (i.e. -5 , -36 , -123, etc...) Thanks again!

Comment: @Nick I think what happened when you changed the [cell] to the reference is that a comma or something got lost in the original formula. Regarding your note "even if I have additional digits" is that regarding that it handles those inputs properly, or that the output is acting unexpected (English can be unclear at times)

Comment: I realized too after posting this thread that I probably could have just used a simply `MID()+1` formula to accomplish this since that character position is fixed, although I dont think that would work if the chacter length of that number is variable.

Comment: Yeah, that was one thing I considered as well, but the length of the number being variable is why I went with the solution I did. There may be an opportunity to handle that dynamically, but since this I knew would work again took this route.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `7` as a constant number in your LEFT function, i'm assuming that the 7characters at the beginning are constant. So with that assumption, you can simply use below formula to automatically add the numbers

```
=CONCAT(LEFT(A11,7),"-",MID(A11,9,IFERROR(FIND("-",A11,9),LEN(A11)+1)-9)+1)
```